# Update problem using validation in request

Tags: laravel, validation, request

I have a validation rule for unique in the update section:

```
'Email' => 'required | unique:users,email'
```

This works for insertion, but fails for update.

How can this be?

Comment: Hi, I tried to clarify your question, please check that it conveys what you wished to ask

Answer (score 0):

So you can add an except to the unique validation rule as well , documented here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique. You pass the id of the row you don't want to include in the check. You can get this is from the route by doing `$this->route('route_param')`

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling save method for updating data?
Then call update method

Example:

```
$new_data = new MyModel();
$new_data->email = 'new@gmail.com';
$new_data->update();
```

update function will update your data.

Comment: i do use request btw i don't use the validation inside the controller